# Null Pointer in getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, service

I'm trying the following piece of code, where a service is implementing my listener:

```
public class MyListenerClass extends Service implements MyListenerInterface {
    public void onCurrencyRecieved(MyEventClass event) {
        System.out.println("Coins Recieved - Listener Successful");
        stopSelf();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();        
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        super.onCreate();
    }
```

Now, the toast inside onCreate() is working fine, but that inside the overridden method is throwing the following exception:

```
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.test.listenertest1.MyListenerClass.onCurrencyRecieved(MyListenerClass.java:28)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.test.listenertest1.MyEventGenerator.generateEvent(MyEventGenerator.java:34)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.test.listenertest1.MyEventGenerator.<init>(MyEventGenerator.java:16)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.test.listenertest1.NewActivity.onKeyDown(NewActivity.java:33)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1037)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2046)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1631)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2368)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2338)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1641)
01-03 18:52:35.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

I guess I'm missing some important java concept. Cant we use getApplicationContext() inside an overridden method ?

Comment: According to the manual (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) you should be able to do it. What's inside of `stopSelf()`?

Comment: Nothing is inside stopself(). Service keeps running until stopself() is called

Answer (score 7):

You should try to avoid using `getApplicationContext()` as much as possible, as this will highly increase the chance of getting Force Closes.

Instead use `YourClass.this`, in this case `MyListenerClass.this`.

I guess in this example it doesn't work, because `getApplicationContext()` is called *after* `stopSelf()`

Comment: Why does calling `getApplicationContext()` increase the chance of getting a Force Close?

Comment: For example if you call it in an overriden OnClick Method it might - depending on the device/firmware/sdk - crash.
Or see the code above: if `this` was used, it would not throw the Exception.

Comment: I have tried using MyListenerClass.this and even removed stopself(). Still it is crashing giving the same log.
Moreover I didnt see anything in the logs which suggests that it's a firmware crash

Comment: Did you override `onCurrencyRecieved`? Because in the code above you didn't.

Comment: onCurrencyRecieved is my listener method

Comment: Have you tried replacing the toast with a Log.d(),? And if yes, did it still crash?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can as this seems to be inside a service, but if it works in `onCreate` (and this code path is actually called) you can easily save the context to a local variable in `onCreate` and then later use it in your method.

Comment: Inside onCreate() I tried this:
mContext = MyListenerClass.this;
and then used mCOntext inside my overridden method. Still it's crashing

Answer (score 0):

Toasts can only be added to Activity like context.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declared it as a new process , in this case you might get the null pointer exception

```
android:process=":MyListenerClass"
```

In Process context getApplicationContext() will not work .

You can verify this by checking the logcat whether TID and PID of you Activity and service are same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `MyListenerClass.this` or `YourActivity.this`

eg.

```
Toast.makeText(MyListenerClass.this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

You've to create context for activity and pass that context.

```
   public static void pushList(Activity context){
  static Context = mConext;

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

          Toast toast=Toast.makeText(mConext,"Succefully Updated Profile",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                 toast.show();

    }
 }
```

this is really working for me.